# Any way to manually validate a CSRF token on the front-end?

Tags: templating, csrf

I'm looking to manually validate a CSRF token (passed via `GET`) in a template, basically as a way of rate-limiting bots accessing a page which generates a CSV file.

Poking around the Craft docs and class reference I can't seem to find anything - but is there a way I can do this in Twig (e.g. `craft.app.validateCsrfToken(token)`)?